# how to put 2 filters if the ng-repeat has a value wrapped in a variable?

Tags: angularjs

I have an ng-repeat which is

```
ng-repeat="sport in sportsFilter = (sports)"
```

and I need to put around 3 filter there

```
ng-repeat="sport in sportsFilter = (sports | filter:query | filter:{hola:query | filter: {leagues: [{hola: secondGreet}] }})"
```

what is the right way ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a predicate function. Predicate functions are passed value and index, and return true or false.

So, in your controller:

```
$scope.predicate = function(val, index) {
    // you can use any kind of logic here, it just needs to
    // return true or false
    if (val.hola == whatever)
        return true;
    else
        return false;
}
```

Then in your markup

```
ng-repeat="sport in sportsFilter | filter: predicate"
```

More info in [the docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/filter)

Comment: is a great solution but is there a way to do it only in html ?

Comment: You can access properties in objects like `filter:{hola:"M", phone:"1"}`, but I'm not sure if you can have multiple filters